# Database Specific Functions in Zend_Db and Zend_Auth

Tags: zend-db, zend-auth

I am using Zend_Db to connect to a postgres database. I want to use some functions in the database, one is built in (the digest() function) and others are one's that are non-core.

Is there a way to allow Zend_Db and/or Zend_Auth to use them? Current it appears to strip out the digest function so I can't store passwords with a salt (for example), other functions like using a built in UUID function don't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with passwords and digest function you can resolve by defining your own function in database, for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sha1(character varying)
RETURNS character varying AS
BEGIN
RETURN ENCODE(digest($1, 'sha1'), 'hex');
END;
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

and for authorization:

```
    $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable(Zend_Registry::get('db'));
    $authAdapter->setTableName('users')
            ->setIdentityColumn('login')
            ->setCredentialColumn('password')
            ->setIdentity($username)
            ->setCredential($password);

    $authAdapter->setCredentialTreatment(
            "SHA1(CONCAT(?,salt))"
    );
```

Zend_Db_Expr also may be helpful